# Pump head suitable for for small tires

Tags: pump

What is the best pump for small bike tires with narrow spokes?

The pump head we have is large and is hard to place over the valve on our 20 inch tire.

I've tried pump extenders but they are screw on and I always let out as much air as I put in when I unscrew them.

I'm happy to get a pump that only works with Schraeder if this makes it easier to find one.

Comment: Just get a standard floor pump with a right-angle chuck.

Comment: @DanielRHicks not a chance on some small wheels, at least not with a reversible head.  I've had to do some with my road morph, where you have to take the head to bits to change valve type - but that means the head is smaller.  Even then it's a tight fit.  An extension hose is better, but you need to unscrew it still attached to the pump

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like the issue that you're having is very similar to the one that time-triallists and triathletes have with disc wheels. Luckily they've come up with a solution for exactly that. What you're looking for is called a disc wheel valve adaptor, often referred to as a "crack pipe" for obvious reason due to its appearance. The most widely used and durable one is the silca version (https://silca.cc/products/disc-wheel-mini-chuck) because of the replaceable seals and tiny head which is easy to fit in the tiny space with the valve. There are plenty of options out there for less money as well such as this one by Fast Forward: 
http://www.wigglestatic.com/product-media/5360051984/ffwd-valve-adapter.jpg?w=430&h=430&a=7

Comment: Does that work for Schraeder?  It says: Threads into any Schrader pump head and Can only be used to inflate Presta valves.   Seems to be conflicting statements?

Comment: It's for presta valves only. A very similar thing exists for Schrader valves which you'll find in most auto parts stores called a 90 degree valve extension. https://www.amxsuperstores.com.au/hard-parts/tools/drc-90-degree-valve-stem-extension?gclid=Cj0KCQiA_s7fBRDrARIsAGEvF8S6Y-H0EYXm3ZzoiLdrUhupcv9Y30vOSr_bFksHjcBjAx8ffxuZbhMaArpqEALw_wcB

Answer (score 2):

Found a good deal on ebay, this part should be perfect for this purpose.

> 90 Degree Motorcycle Car Tire Stem Extender Tyre Valve Extension Adaptor

They are not expensive - one I bought cost $0.99 USD.

[image]  The cap on the right-hand side comes off and reveals a Schrader connection.  These are also available in 135-degree and 60-degree angles.

Comment: Much improved - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A pump with a hose that screws onto the valve sounds like it would do the trick. Something like the [Zefal 800](http://www.zefal.com/en/traditional-pumps/30-800.html), which I link purely as an example of such a product, so show what they look like. This style of pump is easily available and, as I recall, I bought one a few years ago for about £5.